# How to retain colors of texts in rich text box?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I put some colored text to my rich text box my using the following code:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Name";
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
richTextBox1.SelectedText = ": some message.";
```

But when I hide the richtextbox from the user by setting its parent property to null (I have this panel that holds different rich text boxes from time to time), and put it back, the rich text box does not retain the text colors I applied to it. All texts becomes black.

Update: I tried an experiment. In my main program, I have a UserControl (which has a Panel) where I put a RichTextBox with colored text. I have many RichTextBoxes which I store to a HashTable.

So when I need a RichTextBox, I retrieve it from my HashTable, put some colored text into it, put it inside my UserControl's Panel and finally put my UserControl to my program's Form. My UserControl can actually be temporarily removed from the program's Form when a user clicks on a button, I do using Controls.Remove(). To put it back into my Form, I use Controls.Add(). The problem is, when the UserControl is added back, the RichTextBox's texts are not colored anymore.

I tried doing something similar in another experimental program.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

private chat.UserControl1 ChatWindowKuno = new chat.UserControl1();
private Hashtable htChatLogs = new Hashtable(30);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    createRTBox();
}

private void createRTBox()
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
    richTextBox1.Multiline = true;
    richTextBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
    richTextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
    htChatLogs.Add("Basta", richTextBox1);
}        

private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChatWindowKuno.Parent == null)
        ChatWindowKuno.Parent = tabPage2;
    else
        ChatWindowKuno.Parent = null;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear all text from the RichTextBox;

    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = (RichTextBox)htChatLogs["Basta"]; 

    richTextBox1.Clear();

    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Xel";
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = ": Listening to Be My Last by Utada Hikaru.";
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, FontStyle.Italic);
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = " [5:56pm] \n";

    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Gray;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = "[5:56pm] ";
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, FontStyle.Regular);
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Xel";
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    richTextBox1.SelectedText = ": Listening to Be My Last by Utada Hikaru.";

}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox richTextBox1 = (RichTextBox)htChatLogs["Basta"];
    ChatWindowKuno.ChatLog = richTextBox1;
}
}
```

The ChatLog property of usercontrol1 is this:

```
    public Control ChatLogPanel
    {
        get
        {
            return panel1.Controls[0];
        }
        set
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            panel1.Controls.Add(value);
        }
    }
```

I click the 3 buttons randomly in my experimental program, but the text colors are retained.

Comment: Setting the `Parent` property to `null` is a very strange way of "hiding" a control, indeed. From where did you learn this technique? And why do you prefer it over setting `Visible` to `false`?

Comment: The reason why I do this is because I am not just hiding the control (a RichTextBox in my case). It's because I have different RichTextBoxes that I display one at a time depending on what the situation demands. So when I am actually removing one rich text box from a panel I created to add another one to it.

Comment: A panel can contain multiple controls, so there's no problem with adding all of the RichTextBox controls to the panel, and then selectively hiding/showing them by toggling the `Visible` property.

Comment: I need the panel to display only one rich text box at a time which fills the whole panel.

Comment: Toggling the `Visible` property means the others won't be visible. Filling the whole panel has nothing to do with this, that's handled by the `Dock` property. Set it to `DockState.Fill` to make it fill the whole panel.

Comment: I'll try if what you suggests works. But I still want to find out why the texts in my rich text box turns to black when I remove it from the panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `Parent` property to hide, but `Visible` property instead.

If you hide a richtextbox using `richTextBox.Visible = false` it keeps its formatting (tested).

**EDIT :**

as discussed in the comments below, I suggest you to use only one `RichTextBox` and store several `Rtf` strings in a `Dictionary` (or `Hashtable`) to mimic the existence of different `RichTextBox`'es.

An example of what I mean can be found [Here](http://pastebin.com/iaE94wQS)

Comment: I can't use this for my needs. I am actually not just trying to hide a rich text box. The reason I am removing a rich text box from it's parent ( a panel ) is because I need to put another rich text box in that panel. So I can't use this.

Comment: @Xel: I read your updated question. IMO whenever a richtextbox is created, just add it to the panel with `Visible=false`. Then, you just need to make visible the one you need and make invisible the other ones.

Comment: @Xel: BTW, I think it's not necessary to keep all this richtextboxes in the hashtable. You can just keep the text along with the formatting (AKA the `richtextbox.Rtf` string property) an pass it to one single richtextbox. So you can avoid the show/hide problem...

Comment: How can I do that? Where will I store the "richtextbox.Rtf string property" and retrieve it for later use?

Comment: @Xel: Please, have a look at this example I have written for you: http://pastebin.com/iaE94wQS

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I've scanned the code. I will try it later to and see if it solves my problem.

Comment: Hi! What you suggested (storing the Rtf property of the richtextbox in some string variable and retrieve it for later use) works. Post it as an answer so I can choose it as my accepted answer. :)